# Unable to pass a parameter <apex:param> to a relevant method

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Lets assume I have a Page code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allContacts}" var="c" >
            <apex:column value="{!c.id}" headervalue="ID"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.FirstName}" headervalue="First Name"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.LastName}" headervalue="Last Name"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Title}" headervalue="Title"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Company}" headervalue="Company"/>
            <apex:column>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addToRecruits}" value="Recruit">
                    <apex:param assignTo="{!leadID}" name="leadID" value="{!c.id}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

And relevant controller :

```
    public String leadID { get; set; }

    public PageReference addToRecruits() {
        System.debug('LeadID is: ' + leadID);
        List<Lead> potentialCandidate = [SELECT id, FirstName, lastName, Title, Company FROM Lead WHERE id = :leadID];   
        delete potentialCandidate;

        return null;
    }
```

It seems that I can NOT pass `leadID` to `addToRecruits()` method. Do you have any idea why is so?

**UPDATE**:

I could manage to solve it. Instead of querying using SOQL, I approached with this style:

```
public String leadID { get; set; }
public PageReference addToRecruits() {

    Lead candidate=new Lead(id=leadID);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I've had similar code working ok in the past. What result do you see in the log?

Comment: @RobWoodward I solved it . I will update my question to clarify it ..

Answer (score 9):

There's a long outstanding defect with passing parameters from an apex:commandButton.  A hack to get around the defect is to set the rerender attribute on the apex:commandButton element.  See Bob Buzzard's blog: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html

Comment: Another description of the issue from Salesforce: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002664&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I did to solve the situation. I'm new to this platform, and I didn't know that this is a big defect..

Answer (score 3):

It's a "known bug" by the dev community but it never made to the [list](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_index)...

Jeff Douglas has written this up together with viable workarounds in March 2010: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/ (the post and comments also contain few useful links to SF message boards).

Comment: Pramod, congratulations on your copy-paste skills... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4950/799