# apex:param inside knowledge:articlelist

Tags: visualforce, knowledge

I appear to be having issues with apex:param being used inside the knowledge:articlelist component.  I was wondering if anyone had experienced similar issues or possibly (hopefully) knew a fix.

Here is my VF:

> ```
> <ul>
>     <knowledge:articleList articleVar="article" articleTypes="{!articletype}" sortBy="mostViewed" pageSize="10"> 
>             <li>
>                 <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.KnowledgeArticle.View, article.id,['popup' = 'true'])}" target="_blank">
>                       {!article.title}
>                      <apex:param name="articleid" value="{!article.id}" assignto="{!articleid}"/>
>                 </apex:outputLink>            
>             </li>
>     </knowledge:articleList>
> </ul>
> ```

The links never set the parameter.  I set up a commandbutton to do some debugging and the parameter is always null.

Thanks for your help,
Ross

Edit: After reading I felt like I needed to clarify I'm using a custom controller and have set the param assignto variable as public with a getter and setter.

Edit 2: To debug I just created a commandbutton to call a simple method that uses the system.debug.

> Public void debugthis(){
>          system.debug('Article ID is: ' + articleid);
>   }

Comment: Can you share the controller code where you try to debug the articleid.

Comment: I just used commandbutton to call a simple method that debugs the variable:

public void debugthis(){
   system.debug('The value of articleid is' + articleid);
}

Comment: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002664&language=en_US apex:param has never worked with commandbutton instead create a commandlink and mock it to look like a commandbutton.http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/why-does-apexparam-assignto-work-with-apexcommandlink-but-not-apexcommandbutt

Comment: Hey Rao, I appreciate the input but the apex:param isn't associated with the commandbutton.  I should have been more clear, the command button just spits out some debugs in order so I can see them in the logs all in one block.  The param is in conjunction with the articleList component (as you can see with the code) and I think THAT is what's breaking it.  I am wondering if it is the same issue that plagues the use of apex:param with apex:repeat. Hm..