# Commandlink in knowledge:articleList component - method is not called/param doesn't set the parameter

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, articles

When I click on the article title OpenArticlePage() method is not called, the portal homepage just refreshes. < apex:param > tag in the  component doesn't set the parameter. Since the method is not called, I set the debug in another method and the value of the "theArticleId" is always NULL, so the param doesn't set the parameter too.

I found another similar question [apex:param inside knowledge:articlelist](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19251/apexparam-inside-knowledgearticlelist) but I couldn't find an answer.

Any code errors? Thanks in advance.

vf Page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" title="Home Page" controller="PortalHomePageController" standardStylesheets="false" showChat="false" showHeader="false" id="HomePage" >
<style>...</style>
<apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="Results1">
        <knowledge:articleList articleVar="article" pageNumber="{!currentPageNumber}" Keyword="{!ArticleSearchQ}" hasMoreVar="false" pageSize="5" sortBy="mostViewed">
            <table >
                <tr><td>                                        
                    <apex:commandLink value="{!article.title}" action="{!OpenArticlePage}" >
                        <apex:param value="{!article.Id}" name="theArticleId" assignTo="{!theArticleId}" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </knowledge:articleList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- Rest of the Page -->
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class PortalHomePageController {

    public Id theArticleId {get; set;}
    public string TypeOfArticle {get; set;}

    //Other Properties and constructor

    public PageReference OpenArticlePage() {
        System.debug(' theArticleId Value : ' +theArticleId);
        TypeOfArticle = ArticleManager.FindArticleType(theArticleId);
        System.debug(' TypeOfArticle Value : ' +TypeOfArticle);
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/' +TypeOfArticle+ '?id=' + theArticleId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pRef;
    }

    //Other methods
}
```

---

```
Edit 1:
```

As suggested, I changed the datatype of "theArticleId" as string instead of Id, even then the parameter was not set. To Analyze, I coded

```
<apex:commandLink value="Test Run" action="{!test}">
    <apex:param value="test1test1test1" name="test1" assignTo="{!test1}" />
</apex:commandLink>
```

out of the Knowledge:articleList component in the outputpanel. And

```
Controller: public string test1 {get; set;}
```

When the TEST RUN in the Portal was clicked, test() method was called and the value of test1 was set to test1test1test1 and redirected to the correct page. And when the datatype is Id,

```
Controller: public Id test1 {get; set;}
```

test() method was called and the value of test1 was set with the checksum test1test1test1XXX. It might be a string or an Id, it is setting only when the param is passed out of the Knowledge:articleList. Why not inside the component?

Comment: How about using Javascript to pass this as shown below blog :http://salesforceworld.blogspot.in/2011/06/parameter-passing-using.html

Comment: Oh yes @MohithShrivastava. Thanks for the link. I'm curious in knowing what is happening in the Knowledge:articleList component that is not setting the param.

Comment: Hey @MohithShrivastava, I've completed this using the ACTION FUNCTION to pass the value to the controller. But the difficulty now is the rerendering in ActionFunction stops the PageReference being returned. So the same page refreshes without being redirected. Have you overcome this situation before?

Comment: Use on complete event and do navigation in the javascript itself after your method action happens .