# Passing Record ID param from one VF Page to another in the URL

Tags: visualforce, controller

**Background**
I'm working with two VF pages, OutOfOffice and AddNewOutOfOffice.  The OutOfOffice page displays a list of custom object records.  For each record there is an edit and a delete button. There is also a single 'add new' button at the top the OutOfOffice that links to the AddNewOutOfOffice page.

**Issue**
I need the edit button(s) on the OutOfOffice to link to the AddNewOutOfOffice page and pass the record ID into the URL. However with my current code, when I click the edit button I get the url /AddNewOutOfOffice?id=null

Here's what I have so far for the edit button in the VF Page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!OOOrecs}" var="OOO">
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!EditOutOfOffice}"/>
                    <apex:param name="oooIdEdit" value="{!OOO.id}" assignTo="{!oooIdEdit}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteOOO}" rerender="all">
                    <apex:param name="oooIdDelete" value="{!OOO.id}" assignTo="{!oooIdDelete}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
                <br/><br/>
            </apex:repeat>
```

and controller:

```
    public String oooIdEdit {get;set;}

    public PageReference EditOutOfOffice() {
    return new PageReference('/AddNewOutOfOffice/?id='+oooIdEdit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue,use rerender with commandbutton to fix this (or) use command link and style it to make it look like a command button :

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YcV8AAK

[Why does apex:param assignTo work with apex:commandLink but not apex:commandButton?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/why-does-apexparam-assignto-work-with-apexcommandlink-but-not-apexcommandbutt)

Comment: Updated to `<apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!EditOutOfOffice}" rerender="all"/>` but am still having the same issue.  Did I use rerender wrong or is their another workaround for command button?

Comment: @John_Yankee apex:param must be enclosed within `apex:commandButton` - you have it as a peer (sibling)