# how to access id of record in next page from commandlink

Tags: community

I have used this code in one VF page

```
 <apex:column headerValue="updaterecord">     
      <apex:outputLink value="{!urlFor($Page.editpage_vf, null, [id = cs.ID])}">update</apex:outputLink>
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

The question is still worded quiet ambiguously but it appears that you're trying do the similar thing as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/why-does-apexparam-assignto-work-with-apexcommandlink-but-not-apexcommandbutt)

Essentially, you want to pass the parameter (in this case, record id) between your pages. You can use the rerender attribute and hidden page block component as shown below

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="CommandButtonParamController">  
    <apex:form >

        <apex:commandButton value="Process Nickname" action="{!processButtonClick}" rerender="hiddenBlock">
            <apex:param name="nickName"
                value="{!contact.firstname}"
                assignTo="{!nickName}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>

        <apex:pageBlock id="hiddenBlock" rendered="false"></apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

See [this](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/) blog post for full details on this known issue and the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [Global Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global.htm) that could be used on the visualforce page directly. One of them is helpful for you:

**$CurrentPage**

> Use $CurrentPage.parameters.parameterName to reference page request
>   parameters and values, where parameterName is the request parameter
>   being referenced.

There is an example that provides exactly what you need: gets an ID parameter from the `parameters` collection:

```
<apex:page>
    {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}
</apex:page>
```