# Pass record Id from Visualforce to extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this pageBlockTable and I'm trying to pass the parameter in the command button to my extension.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!outstandingCTs}" var="task" id="taskTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">    
    <apex:commandButton value="remove" action="{!deleteActionItem}">
        <apex:param name="taskIdparam"  value="{!task.Id}" assignTo="{!taskIdChosen}"/>
    </apex:commandButton>
```

Here is a some extension code (the standardController is a custom object):

```
    public String taskIdChosen {get; set;}

    public PageReference deleteActionItem (){
        System.debug('taskIdChosen: '+taskIdChosen);
        return null;
    }
```

What can I be missing? I've seen this as a solution many places but I cannot get it to work. taskIdChosen always is null.

This VF page is embedded on the page layout of the custom object. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Can you please paste full code of extension?

Comment: Existing bug from ages : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/why-does-apexparam-assignto-work-with-apexcommandlink-but-not-apexcommandbutt

Comment: Changing it to a commandLink did the trick. Thanks! I've been on this all day.

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's a known bug. Use commandLink instead of commandButton. Thanks Rao!